# Ruby on Rails: validate the presence and existence of an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to know if there is a way in rails to validate the presence (AND existence in the database) of an association **without** using any additional gem if possible (i.e the associated "belongs_to" object is in the database and valid before saving).

`validates_presence_of` does not work because you can use a newly created and unsaved object.

I know all about the `validates_existence` gem but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`validates_associated`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated) in conjunction with [`validates_presence_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of).

`validates_associated` will run validations on the associated model (which you have to define in that model).

`validates_presence_of` validates presence of the association.

**EDIT**

Addressing your comment: not a common scenario to validate presence in db specifically, but you can do this:

```
validate :association_exists

def association_exists
  # query database for the association record and return true if it exists
  # self is model instance inside this method
end
```

Comment: What if the associated object is valid and present but not saved

Comment: How is enforcing the integrity of a belongs_to not a common scenario?  Maybe i did not make myself clear enough...  To me it seems like something i would do in each model.